# Zend Translate + custom url

Tags: php, zend-framework, multilingual

So here is what I have in my bootstrap file

```
/*
* Here the Translator is enabled and passed to
* Zend_Registry so can be accesed from anywhere
*/
public static function translateOption()
{
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Translate');
    $translate = new Zend_Translate(
            'Zend_Translate_Adapter_Csv', 
            self::$root."/lang/en/language.csv", 
            'en');
    self::$registry->translate = $translate;
}
```

**What I'm trying to achive is a URL like mysite.com/language/controller/action**

Here is my route.

```
;Multilang routes
lang_default.type                                = "iM_Controller_Router_Route_Language"
lang_default.route               = ":language/:controller/:action/*"
lang_default.defaults.module     = default
lang_default.defaults.controller = index
lang_default.defaults.action     = index
lang_default.defaults.language   = en
lang_default.reqs.language       = "(ro|en)"
```

And here is the Route controller plugin that I found on the internet:

```
<?php

/**
* Front Controller Plugin; Created by Gabriel Solomon (http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/optimizing-zend-routing/)
*
* @uses       Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
* @category   iM
* @package    iM_Controller
* @subpackage Plugins
*/
class iM_Controller_Plugin_Router extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{
    protected $_dir;
    protected $_default = array();
    protected $_request;

    protected $_initialConfig;
    protected $_remainingConfig;


    public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        // define some routes (URLs)
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();       
        $this->setRequest($request);       

        $config = $this->getInitial();
        $router->addConfig($config);
    }


    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

        $config = $this->getRemaining();

        $router->addConfig($config);
    }

    public function setDir($dir) {
        $this->_dir = $dir;
    }


    public function setDefault($default) {
        if (is_array($default)) {
            $this->_default = array_merge($this->_default, $default);
        } else {
            $this->_default[] = $default;
        }
    }


    public function setRequest(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        //return $this;
    }

    public function getInitial() {
        if ($this->_initialConfig == null) {
            $this->parseIniDir();
        }

        return $this->_initialConfig;

    }


    public function getRemaining() {
        if ($this->_remainingConfig == null) {
            $this->parseIniDir();
        }

        return $this->_remainingConfig;
    }

    protected function parseIniDir() {
        $files = $this->getFiles();
        $this->_default;

        $this->_default[] = $this->determineInitial();

        $this->_initialConfig = new Zend_Config(array(), true);
        $this->_remainingConfig = new Zend_Config(array(), true);       

        if (is_array($files)) {

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $routerFile = $this->compilePath($file);

                if (in_array($file, $this->_default)) {
                    $this->_initialConfig->merge(new Zend_Config_Ini($routerFile));

                } else {
                    $this->_remainingConfig->merge(new Zend_Config_Ini($routerFile));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected function getFiles() {
        if (is_dir($this->_dir)) {
            $dir = new DirectoryIterator($this->_dir);
            $files = array();
            foreach($dir as $fileInfo) {
                if(!$fileInfo->isDot() && $fileInfo->isFile()) {
                    $files[] = $fileInfo->__toString();
                }
            }

            return $files;
        }

        return false;
    }


    protected function getOtherRoutes() {
        $routes->merge(new Zend_Config_Ini($routerFile));
    }


    protected function determineInitial() {
        if ($this->_request) {
            $uri = $this->_request->getRequestUri();
            $base = $this->_request->getBasePath() . '/';

            $request = str_replace($base, '', $uri);
            $requestParts = explode('/', $request);

            $lang = $requestParts[0];
            (array_key_exists(1,$requestParts) ? $section = $requestParts[1] : $section = '');

            if (!empty($section) && $section == 'user') {
                return 'user.ini';
            }

        }
        return false;
    }


    protected function compilePath($file) {
        return $this->_dir . '/' . $file;
    }
}
```

Now my question is how do I change the language, if the url is /en or /ro or /de I guess I have to change it in the bootstrap function `translateOption`but how, I will also like to mention that this has some bugs too...but I will be happy for now If you could help me how to change the language if the url changes, thank you!

I don't know if someone will read this...but hope so

Answer (score 0):

During the bootstrapping process, the application doesn't "know" about what is in your URL yet. Bootstrapping serves to prepare your application, and then to get it running. So after the bootstrapping process, the dispatchloop kicks in. The URL is parsed during the routing, and then when the URL is parsed, the dispatching process calls the module/controller/action associated with the details from the route.

Instead of reading and configuring your translations in the bootstrap, I would suggest doing so in a controller plugin. During various steps of the dispatchloop, certain methods in each controller plugin are called.

Here's a sample:

```
class Application_Model_Language extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeShutdown(\Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        // ask the language from the $request object
        // load the translation data
    }
}
```

Then all you have to do, is tell the Zend_Application that you want to add a plugin into the dispatchloop. This is done during the bootstrapping. So either you put this in your general Bootstrap.php, or in a module-specific Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initTranslations()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $front->registerPlugin(new Application_Model_Language());
}
```